# Delaying Excel Events with CalculationState

Tags: c#, excel

It was my understanding that you can check if Excel is still calculating (i.e. refreshing a query) by using the Calculation state.  So I added in this line to my syntax to ensure that the workbook would not be saved until all queries had been refreshed in the workbook (I even created a test workbook with 1 query and it was saving before that ONE would refresh).  Did I set this up incorrectly, or did I mis-understand the purpose of Calculation state?

```
public Form_Main()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   backgroundworker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   backgroundworker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
   backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
}

private void btnOpenRefreshSave_Click()
{
   backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Excel.Application exApp;
   Excel._Workbook exBook;
   Excel._Worksheet exSheet;

   exBook = (Excel._Workbook)(exApp.WOrkbooks.Open("C:\\Book1.xlsx")); 
   exSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)(exBook.ActiveSheet);
   //This is the line of code that often times takes a while
   exBook.RefreshAll();
   //end of trouble line
   if (exApp.CalculationState == Excel.XlCalculationState.xlDone)
    {
        exBook.SaveAs("C:\\Updated_Book1.xlsx");
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CalculationState refers to the status of the Excel calculation engine (Pending, Calculating, Done) rather than to queries, which are not an integrated part of the calculation engine, (except that running a query could dirty cells and hence trigger a calculation).